# Blocks and retain cycles

Tags: objective-c, ios, block

One minor question: why is Xcode complaining that `listing 1` would lead to a retain cycle, while in `listing 2` it does not? In both cases `_clients` is an `int` instance variable. In `listing 2` it is assigned `0` in the `init` method.

Background info: I would like to execute the loop in the block, as long as at least one client is requesting updates from the iPhone accelerometer, which I am publishing to a redis channel. If there are no more clients left, the loop would quit and stop publishing accelerometer data.

`Listing 2` comes from a small test app I wrote to verify that my idea works. `Listing 1` is implemented in the real project.

### Listing 1

```
- (id)init {
  self = [super init];

  if (self) {
    _clients = 0;

    /**
     * The callback being executed
     */
    _callback = ^ {
      while (_clients > 0) { // Capturing 'self' strongly in this block is likely to lead to a retain cycle
        NSLog(@"Publish accelerometer data to redis (connected clients: %d)", _clients);
      }
    };
  }

  return self;
}
```

### Listing 2

```
- (void)touchedConnectButton:(id)sender {
  _clients += 1;

  dispatch_queue_t concurrentQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
  dispatch_async(concurrentQueue, ^() {
    while(_clients > 0) {
      NSLog(@"Connected clients: %d", _clients);
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In both listings, you are referring to an instance variable, thus implicitly capturing self. A strong self.

This leads to a first solution to your problem:

```
int clients = _clients;
// use `clients` instead of `_clients` in your blocks
```

Alternatively, you can use a weak self:

```
id __weak weakself = self;
// use `weakself->_clients` in your blocks
```

The reason why you got the error in listing 1 is because the block captures self and the block is stored in an instance variable of the same self, leading to a retain cycle. Both solutions above will solve that issue.

Comment: Please note I used `id` for weakself, but you should use the proper type here. If you use Objective-C++, you can declare the local copy `clients` as `auto clients`, inferring the variable type.

Comment: How is Listing#2 a retain cycle??

Answer (score 5):

There is a retain cycle in Listing 1 because in Listing1 self is retaining the ivar _callback in which you access an other ivar, _clients, and because _clients is a primitive var the block retains self to access it !

In Listing2, the block is retained by the queue and not by self.