# recursive block and retain cycles in ARC

Tags: objective-c, recursion, automatic-ref-counting, objective-c-blocks, retain-cycle

EDIT2:

No. The suggested answer is about *async* calls. I want & need synchronous calls, like in a normal, standard recursive call.

EDIT:

while

```
__unsafe_unretained void (^unsafe_apply)(UIView *, NSInteger) ;
```

compiles without warning or errors, it fails at runtime with a NULL stored into unsafe_apply.

However this:

```
- (void) applyToView: (UIView *) view {

    UIColor * (^colorForIndex)(NSInteger) = ^(NSInteger index) {
        return [UIColor colorWithHue: ((CGFloat) index / 255.0f)
                          saturation: 0.5f
                          brightness: 0.5f
                               alpha: 1.0f] ;
    } ;

    void (^applyColors) (UIView *, NSInteger index) = ^(UIView * view, NSInteger index) {
        view.backgroundColor = colorForIndex(index) ;
    } ;

    void (^__block recurse_apply)(UIView *, NSInteger) ;

    void (^apply)(UIView *, NSInteger) = ^(UIView * view, NSInteger level) {
        applyColors(view, level) ;
        [view.subviews enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UIView * subview, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
            recurse_apply(subview, 1+level) ;
        }] ;
    } ;

    recurse_apply = apply ;

    apply(view, 0) ;
}
```

compiles without warnings, but more importantly, actually runs.

But this is **so ugly**!

---

consider *(colouring the view hierarchy, for exposing purpose ...)*:

```
- (void) applyToView: (UIView *) view {

    UIColor * (^colorForIndex)(NSInteger) = ^(NSInteger index) {
        return [UIColor colorWithHue: ((CGFloat) (index * 10.0f) / 255.0f)
                          saturation: 0.5f
                          brightness: 0.5f
                               alpha: 1.0f] ;
    } ;

    void (^applyColors) (UIView *, NSInteger index) = ^(UIView * view, NSInteger index) {
        view.backgroundColor = colorForIndex(index) ;
    } ;

    void (^apply)(UIView *, NSInteger) = ^(UIView * view, NSInteger level) {
        applyColors(view, level) ;
        [view.subviews enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UIView * subview, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
            apply(subview, 1+level) ;
        }] ;
    } ;

    apply(view, 0) ;
}
```

I get this warning:

/Users/verec/Projects/solotouch/SoloTouch/BubbleMenu.m:551:42: `Block pointer variable 'apply' is uninitialized when captured by block`

If I apply the suggested fix: `Maybe you meant to use __block 'apply'`

```
void (^__block apply)(UIView *, NSInteger) = ^(UIView * view, NSInteger level) {
```

I then get: /Users/verec/Projects/solotouch/SoloTouch/BubbleMenu.m:554:13: `Capturing 'apply' strongly in this block is likely to lead to a retain cycle`

I tried various ways to tamper with the code and get rid of those warnings

```
__weak typeof (apply) wapply = apply ;
if (wapply) {
    __strong typeof (wapply) sappy = wapply ;
    wapply(subview, 1+level) ;
}
```

But things just get worse, turning into errors.

I ended up with this:

```
__unsafe_unretained void (^unsafe_apply)(UIView *, NSInteger) ;

void (^apply)(UIView *, NSInteger) = ^(UIView * view, NSInteger level) {
    applyColors(view, level) ;
    [view.subviews enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UIView * subview, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        unsafe_apply(subview, 1+level) ;
    }] ;
} ;

unsafe_apply = apply ;

apply(view, 0) ;
```

Anyone has a better solution, where I could do everything from within the block and not hideously *back patch* it as I had to do here?

Note Those [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11428712/blocks-and-retain-cycles) [Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16725936/retain-cycle-on-an-obj-c-block-using-itself) are about capturing `self` and those [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14839571/block-recursion-and-breaking-retain-cycle) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11696889/arc-with-blocks-and-retain-cycles) don't have any satisfactory answer.

Comment: Like in my edit? But having to back-patch is really ugly, error prone. Isn't there some normal, standard way to use recursive blocks?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Asynchronously dispatched recursive blocks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5394647/asynchronously-dispatched-recursive-blocks) In particular, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/14730061/

Comment: No! The referred to question is about _async_ calls. I need regular, run of the mill, standard recursive calls. No threading involved. At all.

Comment: The solution applies to any recursive Block. Did you try it?

Comment: Are you serious? The "solution" you point at has TWO methods, 20+ lines of code and *is* asynchronous! I am already sad that my own version has 3 unnecessary lines, and you'd suggest that I add even more clutter, and for a result which depends on GCD????

Comment: Chill out for a second and _actually read the answer_. I'm trying to help you solve your problem. There's **three** lines you need: `dispatch_block_t RecursiveBlock(void (^block)(dispatch_block_t recurse)) {
    return ^{ block(RecursiveBlock(block)); };
}`

Comment: @Rob Deville's post uses 2K word to show the solution which fits in 5 lines at the bottom, and is exactly (use of the __block qualifier) what I want to get rid of ... Not to mention that his use of `copy' is superfluous ...

Comment: Who is Rob Deville? I [linked to an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14730061) by a user named "Berik". Instead of arguing with me, why don't you just fix your problem?

Comment: The user @rob gave this link: http://ddeville.me/2011/10/recursive-blocks-objc/ but then apparently deleted his comment. I was replying to him.

Comment: This apparently is an old hat: [bblum](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2009/08/29/blocks-tips-tricks/) has the same `__block` based solution and even [Twitted it](https://twitter.com/bbum/status/3438225542) ... 4 years ago ....

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You need to capture a `__block` variable, because blocks capture non-`__block` variables by value when they are created, and the assignment happens *after* the block has been created.

In ARC, `__block` variables of object pointer type (generally all variables are implicitly `__strong`) are retained by the block. So if the block captures a `__block` variable pointing to itself, it would create a retain cycle. The solution is to have it capture a weak reference. In versions of the OS that support `__weak`, `__weak` should be used instead of `__unsafe_unretained`.

However, if the *only* reference to the block was a `__weak` variable, there would be no strong references to the block, which means it can be deallocated. In order to use the block, it must have a strong reference to keep it around.

Therefore, you need *two* variables, one weak and one strong. The proper way to do it in ARC is:

```
__block __weak void (^weak_apply)(UIView *, NSInteger) ;
void (^apply)(UIView *, NSInteger) ;
weak_apply = apply = ^(UIView * view, NSInteger level) {
    applyColors(view, level) ;
    [view.subviews enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UIView * subview, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        weak_apply(subview, 1+level) ;
    }] ;
} ;

apply(view, 0) ;
```

Comment: When I try this with the latest version of Xcode the compiler flags it with a warning "assigning block literal to a weak variable; object will be released after assignment". Since your approach works exactly around that I assume it's safe to ignore the warning. Do you know how it can be turned off?

Comment: @Drux: changed the order of assignment

Comment: I've tested this with XCode 6, but if I add an allocation inside the block, the memory won't get freed :|

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no.

We can't seem to do better than using the __block qualifier.

##### under ARC

```
__block __weak void(^weakStrawberryFields)();
__block void(^strawberryFields)() = ^() { weakStrawberryFields(); };
weakStrawberryFields = strawberryFields;
strawberryFields();
```

##### pre ARC

```
__block void(^strawberryFields)();
strawberryFields = ^{ strawberryFields(); };
strawberryFields();
```

Thanks to [Bill Bumgarner](https://web.archive.org/web/20200920002901/http://www.friday.com/bbum/2009/08/29/blocks-tips-tricks/) article about blocks.

Comment: This snippet predates ARC; the effect of `__block` has changed since then, and using it without `__weak` creates a retain cycle: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9303704/

Comment: @jscs answer updated for ARC

Answer (score 0):

To avoid ARC warnings and building on @newacct 's answer, I found that setting the weak block inside the retained block works:

```
//a block definition
typedef void (^CompletionType)(NSDictionary * __nullable response, NSError * __nullable error);


//a block calling itself without the ARC retain warning
__block CompletionType completionBlock = nil;
__block __weak CompletionType weakCompletionBlock = nil;
completionBlock = ^(NSDictionary *response, NSError *error) {
    weakCompletionBlock = completionBlock;

        weakCompletionBlock();

    });
};
```

Comment: But then `completionBlock` is a strongly-held object that itself has a strongly-held reference to `completionBlock`. So you've got a retain cycle, exactly the same as if you eliminated all mention of `weakCompletionBlock`.